# sidebar is overlapping footer

Tags: html, css

```css
#allcontents {
  width: 1100px;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}

#sidebar {
  padding: 10px;
  position: sticky;
  top: 20px;
  left: 10px;
  width: 150px;
  border-right: 1px solid black;
  float: left;
}

#main {
  padding: 15px;
  margin-left: 330px;
  margin-bottom: 10px background-color:green;
  width: 800px;
}

#footer {
  background-color: gray;
  clear: left;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>...

<body>
  <div id="allcontents">
    <div id="sidebar">
      random contents
    </div>
    <div id="main">
    </div>
    <div id="footer">
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Sidebar contents overlaps footer when I scroll the page all the way down.

How do I fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can consider solving the issue by adding a `margin-bottom` to your `sidebar`, for example:

```css
#sidebar{
    margin-bottom: 30px;
}
```

Comment: thank you so much! it worked but the border on the right side of sidebar still overlaps with footer. is there any way to fix it? sorry for asking a lot.

Comment: Hi @Rick3dollar, in that case, instead of using `padding-bottom: 30px`, you can use margin instead: `margin-bottom: 30px`

Comment: Thanks again! Now it looks just as I intended.